# Slider Animation, Automatic & Alternative

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a slider, where it allows you to swipe a card left or right. I would like to have the slider swipe left 1 time, and swipe right 1 time, automatically & infinitely.

Can anyone help with this? It will be GREATLY appreciated.

**link to codepen**
http://codepen.io/Taron/pen/jyeIi

**JS below**

```
    window.addEventListener('load', onWndLoad, false);

function onWndLoad() {

    var slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
    var sliders = slider.children;




    var initX = null;  
    var transX = 0;
    var rotZ = 0;
    var transY = 0;

    var curSlide = null;

    var Z_DIS = 50;
    var Y_DIS = 10;
    var TRANS_DUR = 0.4;

     var images=document.querySelectorAll('img');
  for(var i=0;i<images.length;i++)
    {
      images[i].onmousemove=function(e){
        e.preventDefault()

      }
      images[i].ondragstart=function(e){
        return false;

      }
    }

    function init() {

        var z = 0, y = 0;

        for (var i = sliders.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
            sliders[i].style.transform = 'translateZ(' + z + 'px) translateY(' + y + 'px)';

            z -= Z_DIS;
            y += Y_DIS;
        }


        attachEvents(sliders[sliders.length - 1]);



    }
    function attachEvents(elem) {
        curSlide = elem;

        curSlide.addEventListener('mousedown', slideMouseDown, false);
        curSlide.addEventListener('touchstart', slideMouseDown, false);
    }
    init();
    function slideMouseDown(e) {

        if (e.touches) {
            initX = e.touches[0].clientX;
        }
        else {
            initX = e.pageX;
        }


        document.addEventListener('mousemove', slideMouseMove, false);
        document.addEventListener('touchmove', slideMouseMove, false);

        document.addEventListener('mouseup', slideMouseUp, false);
        document.addEventListener('touchend', slideMouseUp, false);
    }
    var prevSlide = null;

    function slideMouseMove(e) {
        var mouseX;

        if (e.touches) {
            mouseX = e.touches[0].clientX;
        }
        else {
            mouseX = e.pageX;
        }

        transX += mouseX - initX;
        rotZ = transX / 20;

        transY = -Math.abs(transX / 15);



        curSlide.style.transition = 'none';
        curSlide.style.webkitTransform = 'translateX(' + transX + 'px)' + ' rotateZ(' + rotZ + 'deg)' + ' translateY(' + transY + 'px)';
       curSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + transX + 'px)' + ' rotateZ(' + rotZ + 'deg)' + ' translateY(' + transY + 'px)';
        var j = 1;
        //remains elements
         for (var i = sliders.length -2; i >= 0; i--) {

        sliders[i].style.webkitTransform = 'translateX(' + transX/(2*j) + 'px)' + ' rotateZ(' + rotZ/(2*j) + 'deg)' + ' translateY(' + (Y_DIS*j) + 'px)'+ ' translateZ(' + (-Z_DIS*j) + 'px)';
        sliders[i].style.transform = 'translateX(' + transX/(2*j) + 'px)' + ' rotateZ(' + rotZ/(2*j) + 'deg)' + ' translateY(' + (Y_DIS*j) + 'px)'+ ' translateZ(' + (-Z_DIS*j) + 'px)';
        sliders[i].style.transition = 'none';
        j++;
        }      



          initX =mouseX;
          e.preventDefault();
          if (Math.abs(transX) >= curSlide.offsetWidth-30) {

              document.removeEventListener('mousemove', slideMouseMove, false);
              document.removeEventListener('touchmove', slideMouseMove, false);
              curSlide.style.transition = 'ease 0.2s';
              curSlide.style.opacity = 0;
              prevSlide = curSlide;
              attachEvents(sliders[sliders.length - 2]);
              slideMouseUp();
              setTimeout(function () {





                  slider.insertBefore(prevSlide, slider.firstChild);

                  prevSlide.style.transition = 'none';
                  prevSlide.style.opacity = '1';
                  slideMouseUp();

              },201);



              return;
          }
    }
    function slideMouseUp() {
        transX = 0;
        rotZ = 0;
        transY = 0;

        curSlide.style.transition = 'cubic-bezier(0,1.95,.49,.73) '+TRANS_DUR+'s';

        curSlide.style.webkitTransform = 'translateX(' + transX + 'px)' + 'rotateZ(' + rotZ + 'deg)' + ' translateY(' + transY + 'px)';
       curSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + transX + 'px)' + 'rotateZ(' + rotZ + 'deg)' + ' translateY(' + transY + 'px)';
        //remains elements
        var j = 1;
        for (var i = sliders.length -  2; i >= 0; i--) {
               sliders[i].style.transition = 'cubic-bezier(0,1.95,.49,.73) ' + TRANS_DUR / (j + 0.9) + 's';
        sliders[i].style.webkitTransform = 'translateX(' + transX + 'px)' + 'rotateZ(' + rotZ + 'deg)' + ' translateY(' + (Y_DIS*j) + 'px)' + ' translateZ(' + (-Z_DIS*j) + 'px)';
           sliders[i].style.transform = 'translateX(' + transX + 'px)' + 'rotateZ(' + rotZ + 'deg)' + ' translateY(' + (Y_DIS*j) + 'px)' + ' translateZ(' + (-Z_DIS*j) + 'px)';

        j++;
        }

        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', slideMouseMove, false);
        document.removeEventListener('touchmove', slideMouseMove, false);

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this could be a solution for automatically slide.
**This is the preview link [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LydLob)**
I have used your code and just added a part for auto slide at the end of your JS code.
It is marked with comment `Auto slider START`.
It will slide one to left and one to right over and over again.

**EDIT**

Yes you can rotate only first card without moving the rest of it, As you mentioned in a comment.
**You can see that new preview here [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EmEqBX)**
In a function `slideMouseMove` you have one `for` loop marked with comment `//remains elements`, just comment whole `for` loop and that will do the job.

Comment: Thanks so much! Do you notice how top card, and the cards behind it, move at at angle, left or right, as they are leaving the deck? Would it be possible if you can only have the top card moving away at the angle, while the others stay put?

Comment: I have added in the post a variant, where slides only the first top card